# How to have custom error messages?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a basic class that takes in 2 integers, but if I want to control the assignment of a variable, how can I do this and raise a defined error message (hiding implementation).

ie.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
       try:
            if var1 < 5:
                self.var1 = var1 
                self.var2 = var2 
             else:
                  raise ValueError
       except ValueError:
             print('Custom Error Message')
```

Comment: `raise ValueError('custom error message')`?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a class that inherits from `ValueError`:

```
class MyException(ValueError):
  pass
```

Then, simply raise the exeption

```
class MyClass():
  def __init__(self, var1, var2):
    if var1 < 5:
       self.var1 = var1 
       self.var2 = var2 
    else:
       raise MyException('Custom Error Message')
```

However, it is even cleaner to create a decorator to wrap the `__init__` method:

```
def check_val(f):
  def wrapper(cls, v1, v2):
     if v1 >= 5:
       raise MyException("Custom Error Message")
     return f(cls, v1, v2)
  return wrapper

class MyClass():
  @check_val
  def __init__(self, var1, var2):
    self.var1 = var1 
    self.var2 = var2
```

Comment: When I create the custom Error class that inherits ValueError, and then I raise the error in the else statement, it prints the error but also with line/file info in which the error happened. How can I hide this implementation details to just show the error message?

Comment: @miweomnwirng The file and line info is part of the builtin traceback and to my understanding cannot be suppressed. For a shorter display, you could use `warnings.warn("Custom warning")`, and then `sys.exit()`